# App name under icon does not displays fully

Tags: ios, ipad, testflight

This only happens on iPad pro in portrait mode. Is there a reason behind this. The full name by the way is Vraagbegrip.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to reduce the length of text. Otherwise you can add some text to app icon and remaining text can be use as app name. But remaining text should be meaning full for your app.

Comment: @Hemal the text is only 11 characters long . It shows fully on every ipad other than ipad pro.

Comment: We can't reduce the reduce the font size in app name. So we have to reduce the character length of the name.

Comment: In that case I think you only need to start the app. The indicator in front of it takes away some of the space. It should be gone once you started it (except when it's a TestFlight build ...)

Answer (score 1):

Max length should be upto 12 letters, but it depends on the width of each individual letter (M takes more room than i). So If you having such text app name will adjust according to screen size.

Comment: Some time i have seen 13-14 also display correct way but text use for app name dont take much space (having letter i,j)

Comment: Google Calendar displays fully and is 15 characters in length.

Comment: The maximum display character has been increased to 15, but people still face this issue. Probably bug from apple's end. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundlename